# call stack depth: Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: xcode

My call stack depth seems to always be 2 calls. It's been like this for a couple of weeks. It might have been triggered by an Xcode update.

And *yes*, the slider at the bottom of the Debug Session window in the Navigator is to the right.

Anyone that has experienced the same problem?

I'm running Objective C (mixed with some C++ code) for iOS, if that is of any interest.

Comment: for all projects or just the one you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back to the normal stack depth now. I really don't know, but I have restarted Xcode. Maybe that fixed the problem.